# Ionic - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, php, api, mobile, ionic-framework

I am currently developing a mobile application with Ionic though I blocked with my login system .. The purpose is to send information entered by the user through POST and then that "API" of my site checks it all and turn around the result

But I have the following error :

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myfinance.byethost11.com/MyFinanceAPI/index.php. Origin http://localhost:8100 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Yet I have tried to search information on the cross domain but impossible to run it... I think it comes from my server configuration or there api .. But I do not know how to do if you have a solution ?

My ionic controller :

```
controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log,$state){
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.login = function() {
    var request = {
      method: "post",
      url: "http://myfinance.byethost11.com/MyFinanceAPI/index.php",
      data: {
      user: $scope.user.username,
      password: $scope.user.password
    },
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    };
    $http(request).then(function (response){
      if (response.data == '1'){
        alert('Bienvenue !');
        $state.go('home');
      }
      else {
        alert('Connexion impossible');
      }
    })
  }
})
```

My API :

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$user = $request->user;
$password = $request->password;

if($user == 'test'){
  echo '1';
}else{
  echo '0';
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: maybe this will help http://ionicinaction.com/blog/how-to-fix-cors-problems-and-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-errors-with-ionic/

Answer (score 0):

Try it and let me know if it work.

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400'); 
}

// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}

echo "You have CORS!";
```

Comment: I have tried just now. I have put this code in my php file (the API) but always the same error...

Comment: ok I found this information maybe it could help you http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: I have test on a other host and it work with just this line header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); I don't understand .. But it work !!